# Need Help escaping an apostrophe in CSV -->SQL using PHP

Tags: php, csv, escaping

OK I know I probably need to use a str_replace and I have tried `$thequery = str_replace("'", "''", $thequery);` but it didn't work. Please don't ding me on the code...I didn't write it. Each week we get a txt file done like a CSV with all our course offerings and we copy and paste it into a web page with the following code and it gets posted to an MSSQL table...however sometimes we have a course name with an ' and then it doesn't load and we have to manually remove the '. I need to escape the ' and can use some help.

```
if ($_POST) {

    if(isset($_POST['semester'])) {
        # Table name to upload to
        $tablename = $_POST['semester'];
    } else {
        die("No table to use");
    }

    # Parsing of the text
    $thequery = $_POST['sql'];
    $thequery = str_replace("\"", "'", $thequery);
    $thequery = str_replace(".00", "", $thequery);
    $thequery = str_replace(".50", "", $thequery);
    $thequery = str_replace("'Brien", " Brien", $thequery);
    $thequery = str_replace("'Shaughnessy", " Shaughnessy", $thequery);
    $thequery = str_replace("--", "10-01-01", $thequery);
    $thequery = str_replace("WEB", "Online", $thequery);
    $squery = explode("\n", $thequery);

    $names = array();
    $equery = array();
    $i = 0;

    foreach($squery as $newquery) {
        $a = split('[*]', $newquery);
        $final = substr($a[0], 0, -2); 
        $newid = $a[1];
        $names[$i] = $newid;
        $equery[$i] = $final;
        $i++;
    }

    $scount = 0;

    # Easiest way to redo the course list was to drop the table and re-insert it with the new values

    mssql_query("DROP TABLE [dbo].[$tablename]") or die(mysql_error());

    mssql_query("CREATE TABLE [dbo].[$tablename] (division CHAR(4) NULL, cid CHAR(11) NULL, cname CHAR(45) NULL, credits TINYINT NULL, days CHAR(7) NULL, day_M TINYINT NULL, day_T TINYINT NULL, day_W TINYINT NULL, day_R TINYINT NULL, day_F TINYINT NULL, day_S TINYINT NULL, sdate DATETIME NULL, edate DATETIME NULL, stime DATETIME NULL, etime DATETIME NULL, duration CHAR(5) NULL, building CHAR(3) NULL, room CHAR(4) NULL, method CHAR(12) NULL, instructor CHAR(40) NULL, secsyn INT NULL)") or die(mysql_error());

    # Inserts the courses

    while ($scount < count($equery)) {

        mssql_query("INSERT INTO [dbo].[$tablename] (division, cid, cname, credits, days, day_M, day_T, day_W, day_R, day_F, day_S, sdate, edate, stime, etime, duration, building, room, method, instructor, secsyn) VALUES ($equery[$scount])") or die(mysql_error());
        print($equery[$scount] . " has been entered.<br>");


        $scount++;

    }

    # Quick hack to update the "Last Updated" with the current date
    $date = date("M j Y g:iA");
    mssql_query("UPDATE courses SET updated='$date' WHERE id='ABED140'") or die(mysql_error());

    $nq = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[$tablename] WHERE method='Online'") or die(mysql_error());
    $tnum = 0;

    print("<br /><br />");

    # Sets courses to Hybrids if they have a 'H' in the course ID
    while($tnum < mssql_num_rows($nq)) {
        $tcourse = mssql_result($nq,$tnum,"cid");

        $ccode = explode(" ",$tcourse);

        if(isset($ccode[1])) {
            if (strpos($ccode[1], 'H') !== false) {
                mssql_query("UPDATE [dbo].[$tablename] SET method='Hybrid' WHERE cid='$tcourse'") or die(mysql_error());
                print("Updated " . $tcourse . " to be a Hybrid course.<br />");
            }
        }

        $tnum++;
    }

    # Special cases for certain classes that need to be set as a Hybrid
    # Simply add $sq[NEXT NUMBER] = "COURSE ID"; and it will set it to a Hybrid

    $sq = array();
    $sq[0] = "BIOL101 WH";
    $sq[1] = "BIOL140 WH";

    foreach ($sq as $nq) {
        if(mssql_num_rows(mssql_query("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[$tablename] WHERE cid='$nq'")) > 0) {
            mssql_query("UPDATE [dbo].[$tablename] SET method='Hybrid' WHERE cid='$nq'") or die(mysql_error());
            print("Updated " . $nq . " to be a Hybrid course.<br />");
        }
    }

    # Checking to make sure the online classes have a special_online table link

    $cq = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[$tablename] WHERE method='Online' OR method='Hybrid'");
    $cn = 0;

    while($cn < mssql_num_rows($cq)) {

        $ccid = mssql_result($cq,$cn,"cid");
        $ncq = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[special_online] WHERE cid='$ccid'");

        if(mssql_num_rows($ncq) == 0) {
            mssql_query("INSERT INTO [dbo].[special_online] (cid,url) VALUES ('$ccid','http://dacc.blackboard.com')") or die(mysql_error());
            print("Updated " . $ccid . " to have a online course link.<br />");
        }

        $cn++;
    }

} else {    
    # Prints our form that shows when page is first loaded
    print("<form action='' method='post'><select name='semester'>
    <option value='2011SP'>2011SP</optoin>
    <option value='2011SU'>2011SU</option>
    <option value='2011FA'>2011FA</option>
    <option value='2011FA'>2011WI</option>
    <option value='2012SP'>2012SP</option>
    <option value='2012SU'>2012SU</option>
    <option value='2012FA'>2012FA</option>
    <option value='2013SP'>2013SP</option>
    <option value='2013SU'>2013SU</option>
    <option value='2013FA'>2013FA</option>  
    <option value='2013WI'>2013WI</option>
    <option value='2014SP'>2014SP</option>
    <option value='2014SU'>2014SU</option>
    <option value='2014FA'>2014FA</option>
    </select><br><br>Insert the statement:<br><textarea name='sql' rows='10' cols='100'></textarea><br><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>");
}
```

Comment: have you tried to get it into the database as a escaped quote? `$thequery = str_replace("'", "\'", $thequery);`

Comment: No I didn't. Didn't even think of that.

Comment: I will try it momentarily

Comment: I just noticed you are using `mssql_` functions, I'm not sure if it's the case, but at least the `mysql_` functions are deprecated, unmaintained, and dangerous due to the sql injections. And your problem is showing that you are very vulnerable to them. I would refactor the code using `PDO` or similar, which escapes by default and manages in a cleaner way the SQL sentences. You will avoid the unescaped character issues, the code will be easier to maintain and reutilize as it's OOP.

Comment: @aleation we are currently in the process of a complete site redesign so we won't be using this code much longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace `'` with `\` before you put that in your database:

Change this line:

```
$thequery = str_replace("\"", "'", $thequery);
```

to:

```
$thequery = str_replace("'", "\\", $thequery);
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/DhsXe)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will see if we can get it to work.